# How to append to the end of a line before the first pattern match?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file containing some random data like:

```
number1 number2 number3
&END
```

I want to add a \ to the end of the line containing number3, but I cannot match a pattern on that line as that number keeps changing. So I try matching "&END" in sed and then append a line before it, but that does not work for me because it creates a new line, like

```
number1 number2 number3

\

&END
```

My desired output is

```
number1 number2 number3 \
&END
```

Also, I only need to make this change at the first occurence of &END in the file.
Is there a way to do this using sed, or maybe awk?

EDIT: My input file is test.restart, that looks like:

```
&COORD

1.4089452021105357E+01  1.3165670625576730E+01  1.2727066323166799E+01 \
 ...

 ...

1.3549295360587577E+01  1.2120902691780184E+01  1.2741652733169291E+01

&END
...
...
&COORD

H 3475843 73457834 7346587435
...
...
&END
```

I only need to make the changes in the block of text before the first occurence of &END.

Comment: You need to add some real-world examples to make your question solvable.

Comment: @pLumo  Real world examples of what? My tried solutions that don't work?

Comment: I mean of the input data. ("*end of the line containing number3, but I cannot match a pattern on that line as that number keeps changing.*"). What is your real-world "*number3*" then? Or better:  how do you know that this is the line you want to match?

Comment: Another hint: Use `code` styling instead of `quote` styling would make your question better  readable. You can edit your question.

Comment: okkkk... your real-world example is very different to your simpified example. The \ should not come at the end of the line before `&END`... Will it be in the next line after `&COORD` instead?

Comment: @pLumo No, that \ at the end of the line after &COORD is already present. I now want to put it at the end of the line before &END.

Comment: ah good, then my answer is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed -z` and include `\n` in your pattern:

> **-z, --null-data**
> separate lines by NUL characters

```
sed -Ez 's/(\n+&END)/ \\\1/' file
```

`sed` by default replaces only the first occurency per line. As you have only one line if you use NUL-delimiter, you're fine.

`-E` tells `sed` to use Extended Regex (ERE) instead of Basic Regex (BRE). You can omit the flag, but then you need to escape the braces:

```
sed -z 's/\(\n+&END\)/ \\\1/' file
```

---

**Output:**

```
&COORD

1.4089452021105357E+01  1.3165670625576730E+01  1.2727066323166799E+01 \
 ...

 ...

1.3549295360587577E+01  1.2120902691780184E+01  1.2741652733169291E+01 \

&END
...
...
&COORD

H 3475843 73457834 7346587435
...
...
&END
```

---

Note, `-z` is fine in Ubuntu, but not available in all `sed` implementations and thus not a portable solution.

Comment: Can you tell me what the -E flag is for? And can I use the -i with it, because I want to edit this into the same file?

Comment: Yes, you can use `-i` if you're fine with the output. Added explanation for `-E`.

Comment: I get the error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: sure, you use the same command ?

Comment: Yes, I even copy pasted

Comment: Both work fine for me. which Ubuntu version? I get this error when using the first version without `-E` which is expectable

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Same version here. Should work just fine, cannot tell anymore, I'm sorry.

Comment: I tried the other option without the -E flag, and that does not give any error but it doesn't do the job either.

Comment: Good idea @bac0n.